# Heroku "Application error" when deploying Sinatra (Ruby) app

Tags: ruby, heroku, deployment, sinatra

Although the app works perfectly on development mode, I keep on getting the classic "Application error" when the app is already "Build succeeded" and "deployed", according to Heroku.
Here's what the logs say:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=a14f3fa7-6b65-4b5f-9207-f8a1d6e9fd8a fwd="209.122.239.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.7.2"

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'activerecord', :require => 'active_record'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord', :require => 'sinatra/activerecord'
gem 'rake'
gem 'require_all'
gem 'thin'
gem 'shotgun'
gem 'pry'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'tux'
gem 'sinatra-flash'

group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
 gem 'tux'
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'database_cleaner', git: 'https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner.git'
end
```

My config.ru:

```
require './config/environment'
require './app'

if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.needs_migration?
  raise 'Migrations are pending. Run `rake db:migrate` to resolve the issue.'
end

use Rack::MethodOverride
run Sinatra::Application
run ApplicationController
use UsersController
use TasksController
```

database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
  username: app
  password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

environment.rb:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require
configure :development do
 ENV['SINATRA_ENV'] ||= "development"
require 'bundler/setup'
 Bundler.require(:default, ENV['SINATRA_ENV'])
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "sqlite3",
  :database => "db/#{ENV['SINATRA_ENV']}.sqlite"
 )
end
```

I already ran "heroku rake db:migrate".

I've looked around quite a lot, but nothing solved it so far. Never had so many issues trying to deploy such a simple web app. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "sqlite3",
  :database => "db/#{ENV['SINATRA_ENV']}.sqlite"
 )
end
```

SQLite doesn't work on Heroku. You have to use the PostgreSQL adapter and connection. These [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) have more information.

Comment: Already switched to:
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "postgresql",
  :database => "db/#{ENV['SINATRA_ENV']}.postgresql"
 )
And pushed to Heroku again. Didn't make a difference and still not working

Comment: `database => "db/#{ENV['SINATRA_ENV']}.postgresql"` isn't a valid PostreSQL connection string. Heroku provides a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. So it should be something like: `database => ENV['DATABASE_URL']`. You also have to add the Heroku PostgreSQL add-on as mentioned in the docs I linked to above.